# Problem with launching JAGUAR in R

Tags: r

Windows XP, R 2.11.1, Java JRE6

I just installed the Jaguar package.

From an R console, I can do this:

```
> library(JGR)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: JavaGD
Loading required package: iplots

Please use the corresponding JGR launcher to start JGR.
Run JGR() for details. You can also use JGR(update=TRUE) to update JGR.
```

and so JGR appears to be correctly installed.

`JGR()` yields

```
On Windows JGR must be started using the JGR.exe launcher.
Please visit http://www.rosuda.org/JGR/ to download it.
>
```

I'm not sure how to run Jaguar - I know I have to run jgr.exe - but should R be already open?  If so, should the JGR library be already loaded?  I've tried all of these, and what seems to happen regardless is a console window opens briefly, then disappears.  I've run jrg --debug, with no apparent error message: (same file regardless of choice made above).

What should I be doing?

Thanks!

System: Version 5.1 (build 2600), platform 2 [Service Pack 3]

```
JGR loader version 1.61 (build Jul 23 2008)

parseParams> 1 parameters parsed.
parseParams par 10> "--debug"
> rhome="C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.1"
> srhome="C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1"

getPkgVersion(JGR): 010702
getPkgVersion(rJava): 000805
getPkgVersion(JavaGD): 000503
getPkgVersion(iplots): 010103

Loading preferences from "C:\Documents and Settings\gblais\.JGRprefsrc"
> javakey="Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6"
> javah="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"
> tp="C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files\Tcl\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\BIN;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;c:\belfry;c:\belfry\usr\local\wbin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WBEM;c:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;c:\progra~1\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\"
Got RuntimeLib from registry, using "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client;" PATH prefix.
Java home: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"
R home: "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.1"
JAR files: "-Drjava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\rJava\jri\JRI.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\iplots\java\iplots.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\JGR\java\JGR.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\etc\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\etc\classes.jar"
desired PATH: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\rJava\jri;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files\Tcl\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\BIN;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;c:\belfry;c:\belfry\usr\local\wbin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WBEM;c:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;c:\progra~1\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\"
actual PATH: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\rJava\jri;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files\Tcl\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\BIN;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;c:\belfry;c:\belfry\usr\local\wbin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WBEM;c:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;c:\progra~1\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\"
getenv PATH: "C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files\Tcl\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\BIN;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;c:\belfry;c:\belfry\usr\local\wbin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WBEM;c:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;c:\progra~1\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\"
argv[0]:C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe
argv[1]:-Drjava.class.path=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\rJava\jri\JRI.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\iplots\java\iplots.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\JGR\java\JGR.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\etc\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\etc\classes.jar
argv[2]:-Xmx512m
argv[3]:-cp
argv[4]:C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\rJava\java\boot
argv[5]:-Drjava.path=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-211~1.1\library\rJava
argv[6]:-Dmain.class=org.rosuda.JGR.JGR
argv[7]:-Djgr.load.pkgs=yes
argv[8]:-Djgr.loader.ver=1.61
argv[9]:RJavaClassLoader
argv[10]:--debug
```

Comment: Maybe I'm too late to this one (and I don't have much Windows experience), but did you install these packages as administrator? The launcher may only look in a certain directory structure (i.e., the all users folders as opposed to your user folder)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instructions from the [JGR website](http://rosuda.org/JGR/down.shtml)?

> Installation instructions:
>
> 1. Download and install R 2.5.0 or higher (Linux/Solaris: make
>      sure --enable-R-shlib was used when
>      compiling R)
> 2. Download the appropriate JGR application for your OS from above
>      (Windows/Mac OS X) or install JGR
>      package from CRAN.
> 3. Start the JGR application! JGR will install all necessary packages
>      directly from CRAN (or the RoSuDa
>      server). (You should have
>      administrator rights to get the
>      packages installed)
> 4. After step 3 completed successfully, JGR is fully installed
>      and can be used.
>
> **Windows users:** if you have more than one JDK version installed, you
>   can use this tiny tool to select the
>   default version that will be used with
>   JGR: [jselect.exe](http://rosuda.org/JGR/jselect.exe).
>
> The Windows launcher accepts the
>   following optional command line
>   parameters:
>
> --debug - show debugging info and create c:/jgrdebug.txt (must be the
>   first parameter if used)
>
> --rforge - use www.rforge.net for package installation instead of CRAN
>   (useful to install latest development
>   packages)
>
> --cran=xxx - use xxx as CRAN mirror for package installation
>
> --libs=xxx - use xxx as package location (use only if you don't have
>   write permission in the default R
>   package location)